# ¿Cómo llenar un "option" de un "select" de "html", desde la "bd" con "php" pero que se llene hasta que los otros campos de un formulario estén llenos?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

estoy haciendo un formulario en html con dos campos de texto, uno donde se ingresa la contraseña, el segundo donde se escribe el usuario y opciones de un select, donde se escribe la empresa, de la cual puede haber varias opciones, justo por eso es un "Select" con varias opciones, la función que hace es que, al escribir una contraseña en el campo correspondiente y presionar la tecla enter, con Ajax, verifica en la base de datos si esa contraseña existe, y si es así, se llena automáticamente el campo de texto de usuario, y debería llenarse también el "option", pero justo aquí es el problema que tengo, que el text de usuario, se llena perfectamente con el dato que le corresponde desde la bd al presionar enter en el text de contraseña; pero el option de empresa no se llena, no se muestra nada, si no que se queda vacío. Lo que deseo es que al estar ya todos los campos llenos, con el botón submit, ingresar a otra página e iniciar sesión con el id del usuario que está ingresando, pero eso es posterior, el problema actual es lo que mencioné anteriormente, cómo llenar también el option hasta presionar enter y consultar si existe la contraseña en la bd, que no aparezcan las opciones al momento de cargar la página, si no que, al igual que todos los demás campos, esté vacío y se llene, así como se llena automáticamente el campo de usuario, al presionar enter en contraseña. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comparto mi código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inicio.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Gestión 2022</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="divarriba">

       <h5>SDIG</h5>
       <h6>Gestión</h6>

       <div class="icon2 icon-key"></div>

       <h1>Gestión Web</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="esquina"></div>

    <table class="ingresardatos">
        <tr>
<form method="POST">
    <td><h2 class="contraseña">Contraseña:</h2></td> <td class="td"><input class="boxcontraseña" id="contraseña" type="text" name="contraseña" autocomplete="off" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><h2 class="usuario">Usuario:</h2></td> <td><input type="text" class="boxusuario" id="usuario" name="usuario" disabled style="background:transparent; border:none;" value=""></td>
    </tr>

            <td><h2 class="empresa">Empresa:</h2></td>
            <td><select name="empresa" id="empresa" value="" style="width:98%; height:calc(1.2em + 1.2vw);" >

               
            
            
            <option value="0"></option>

           
                </select></td>
        </tr>

        
    </table>

<div id="Oculto"></div>
<script>
$("input[name='contraseña']").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $.post('ingresar.php', {
            contraseña : $("input[name='contraseña']").val()
        }, function(data){
            $('#Oculto').html(data);
        });
    }
});
</script>

<div class="divabajo">

<table class="botonesabajo">
<tr>
<td><label style="color:green; background: white; font-size: calc(1em + 1vw); border-radius: 45%; width: 20%;"><input type="submit" id="register" disabled class="btingresar" value="Ingresar" name="register"></td>
<td><button class="btcancelar"><label style="color:white; font-size: calc(1em + 1vw);"></label> Cancelar</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


</div>
<?php
    include ("ingresar.php");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Y mi código php:

```
<?php

$conex = mysqli_connect("SERVIDOR", "USUARIO", "CONTRASEÑA", "BD");
if ($conex->connect_error) {
    die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '. $conex->connect_error .'</p>');
  } else {
    echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server successfully established.</p>';
  }
?>



<script>
    $("input[name='usuario']").val('');
</script>
<?php
$contraseña = (is_numeric($_POST['contraseña']))?$_POST['contraseña']:NULL;
if(!is_null($contraseña)){
    $consulta = 'SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE contraseña= '.$contraseña.';';
    $fila = $conex->query($consulta);
    $registro = $fila->fetch_assoc();
    $totalfilas = $conex->affected_rows;
    if($totalfilas == 0){
        echo "<script>alert('No hay valores que coincidan con la búsqueda.');</script>";
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>
            $("input[name='usuario']").val("<?php echo $registro['usuario'];?>");    

            <?php
            $getempresa1 = 'SELECT * FROM clientes order by id';
            $getempresa2 = mysql_query($getempresa1);

          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getempresa2))
          {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $empresa = $row['empresa'];

            ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $empresa;?></option>
            <?php
          }
          ?>
          
        </script>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Estás metiendo un valor no numérico');</script>";
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

Y adjunto una fotografía de cómo es el formulario para comprender mejor lo que deseo hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es decir, el usuario puede poner la contraseña que se le ocurra y el aplicativo busca una coincidencia en la base de datos para traer el usuario asociado a esa contraseña?. Me suena un poco descabellada esa lógica, se puede prestar para ataques. Y, si dos o mas usuarios tienen la misma contraseña que pasa?

Comment: @DjCrazy Tienes razón amigo, ya tomé en cuenta eso, por ello, pedirá también ingresar correo electrónico, pero eso no le he incluido aún, por ahora quiero aclarar el problema que no he resuelto, que es llenar también el option, muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo creo que deberías integrar altiro el correo electrónico y no usar la contraseña.

Comment: @MaikelYordan Sii tienes toda la razón amigo, enseguida haré eso, pero lo que necesito solucionar es lo que comenté anteriormente, llenar el option desde la bd al hacer enter. Te agradezco por tu comentario!!!!